# Running on one core instead of two i5-3317u. UX32VD

Tags: zenbook, ivy-bridge

Im using the i5-3317u ux32vd zenbook.
When I got it two weeks ago, it was running at 2 cores. It had respectable windows experience index back then. However, yesterday my zenbook became laggy and I found out that the windows experience in term of calculation speed is 4.5! And checked that it is only running on one core. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: what changed between two weeks ago and now .. in terms of what have you changed / installed / deinstalled / tuned / "improved"?

Comment: I forgot to add that I have replaced the stock ram with a strontium 8gb ddr3 1600mhz. it was working fine for a day before I experience the lag. Thank you!